# add anchor tag to accordion

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an external link to go to a certain section within my accoridian terms and conditions page, I've managed to link it up from 1 accordian tab to another, but how can i do it so it opens up a tab from another page? E.g. email links etc.  Ideally I would like to link to certain sections within the accordion tabs but if that's not possible, opening the correct accordion will be fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Click <a class="opener" data-panel="3" href="#section2">here</a> to open section 2</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel" id="section2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}

var opn = document.getElementsByClassName("opener");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < opn.length; i++) {
  opn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var href = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf("#")+1);
    var panel = document.getElementById(href);
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add Like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">here</a>
```